# Session terminated due to SO_TIMEOUT

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I'm having a problem with my tests from my Jenkins server (this doesn't happen in my local computer). When I run some tests (that they get more time to load every information in the graphic than others tests), I get the following error and it stops the execution:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session [50e7a38f-969a-41b6-8e04-66cdf989fb6c] was terminated due to SO_TIMEOUT
Command duration or timeout: 28 milliseconds
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:437)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElements(By.java:356)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:398)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:882)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:644)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:641)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:209)
    at paquete.ImagenMarca_SantanderAnualTest.main(ImagenMarca_SantanderAnualTest.java:110)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:106)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

I can't find a solution nowhere, do you know any ideas?

Thanks so much in advanced.

Comment: Please put relevant code at here

Comment: Could you give more detail informatino about, 1) did you use selenium server/grid,  and it's the same machine as Jenkins Server,  2) did your job run on the Jenkins Slave which is the same machine of Jenkins Server,   3) What OS is the Jenkins Slave and Selenium server/ grid, linux or window?

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using?
I read that this issue disppeared in version 3.x

Answer (score 1):

**Analysis:**

The SO_TIMEOUT means socket timeout, it happened when selenium client not recevie the http response from webdriver within timeout.

**Solution:**

script machine:  where your test script on

1) If any selenium api call like click(), getText() will report SO_TIMEOUT every time

a) if use selenium server/grid,  make sure the scirpt machine can opent the server/gird url in browser

Reminder: the  script machine may be Jenkins server or Jenkins Slave, dependents on your Jenkins Job configured job run on where

b) if not user selenium server/grid,  runnig will start a webdriver.exe in seperate process on script machine and this process wil run on on a port of script machine, so check there is no thing will block the traffic on the port, likelinux machine, you turn on the fireware and only allow traffic on partial ports, even maybe only allow out traffic, but in traffic on one port.

2) if just report SO_TIMEOUT on random selenium api call, and not every time.

The possible reason is network traffice not table and good.